# UITextField without borders and with shadows

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, border, shadow

I am struggling with a silly thing I guess... Here is my problem. I want to get rid of my rounded gray border make it hidden or transparent so we can only see the shadows.

Here is my situation:

[image: Actual Result]

with this following code:

```
 private func styleTextField(textField: UITextField)
{
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
   //textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
   // textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    //textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
}
```

But I want this following result:

[image: Final wanted result]

Of course, I think I can achieve that but embed it inside a view, but It's not clean at all especially for this kind of things.

Any idea on how to achieve that ? Or Fix this ?

EDIT 1 : Actual code after suggestions. If this can help.

`class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var facebookButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var connectButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nomField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var prenomField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    emailField = self.styleTextField(emailField)
    passField = self.styleTextField(passField)
    nomField = self.styleTextField(nomField)
    prenomField = self.styleTextField(prenomField)

    self.styleButton(self.connectButton)
    self.styleButton(self.facebookButton)
}


private func styleTextField(textField: UITextField) -> UITextField
{
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor


    textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
    textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0)

    return textField
}
```

}`

EDIT 2: Type of border when I create it in my Storyboard.
[image: Border type at creation]
Regards,

Hary

Comment: did you try no border setting ?

Comment: can you try , dont use - rounded rect border, give borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None, and then give rounded rect by textfield.layer.cornerRadius. I think it will solve your problem

Comment: textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None --> this ? Yea but it also get rid of the shadows ...
Just tried what you said... Result = No Border (COOL) but No Shadows (NOT COOL)

Comment: have you tried 'UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)' rather than 'white-color'? Sometimes makes a difference.

Comment: Not working too ... seems like no matter what color I give it doesn't change.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4.2:**

Made it work using those lines by concentrating everything on the layer:

```
private func styleTextField(textField: UITextField){
    textField.borderStyle = .none
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
}
```

Thanks for your help guys !

Regards,

Hary

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = false

    textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 50.0
```

and then continue
[image]

Comment: `private fun styleTextField(textField: UITextField)
    {
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    }
`
Not Working

Comment: I have added the code. use in the same order, it is working for me

Comment: @NitinGohel yes it is.

Comment: @S.Hary I have added screenshot.

Comment: @S.Hary I would not set borderwidth to 0

Comment: `private func styleTextField(textField: UITextField)
    {
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0)
    }`

Still not working though .... I don't know why ...

Comment: are you returning this textField back? you are changing the textfield in the function.. But where do you use the altered textfield.

Comment: Can you show me how you are calling this function? I think I know where your problem lies now/

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nomField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var prenomField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        self.styleTextField(emailField)
        self.styleTextField(passField)
        self.styleTextField(nomField)
        self.styleTextField(prenomField)

    }` Calling the function here

Comment: Change `self.styleTextField(emailField)` to `emailField = self.styleTextField(emailField)`. This is because you want to get the textfield that you changed. And add a return statement to your function
`private func styleTextField(textField: UITextField)` to `private func styleTextField(textField: UITextField) -> UITextField` and at the end in this function add, `return textField`

Comment: hmm should I reference it instead ? But i think your solution is gonna work. I hope. I ll let you know.
Edit after change = Still not working

Comment: This is really weird. It works here perfectly, I have been practicing this for months now.

Comment: I have edited the question so you can see better. It is really weird though, I have a function for UIButton too for the same purposes, it works fine. Nothing is working on TextField....

Comment: only difference i see is self.connectButton and you are not using self.emailField. But that should not matter.

Comment: Made some new edit on the question, if this can help. I found this thing super weird. Why it doesn't change at all... Why ??!!!

Comment: Do you want to try it programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically is not very efficient for me. Especially if I want to change the layout of those fields and stuff. I could but it's not an option i should consider.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2 code is IBDesignable Shadow class easily use with storyboard and view all change**

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomTextfiled: UITextField {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}


@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
    didSet {

        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.shadowColor = borderColor.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
        layer.shadowRadius = 4.0

    }
}
```